# Is it good idea to use OrientDB memory database as session handler instead of REDIS

Tags: node.js, session, redis, orientdb

I am thinking to use OrientDB as session storage solution for my node.js app. Is there any benchmark for Redis and OrientDB?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, a key-value being that it is one of the most simple forms of indexing/relating data it will likely be the fastest. Graph databases are fast also, but they're not considered for their speed in general but more so their ability to manage complicated relations. They happen to be fast at this by design, because thats what they were designed to do. However, try to do the same thing in a traditional RDBMS as you would typically in a graph database and you'll likely have trouble scaling and performing these operations in a reasonable amount of time.

What it really comes down to is which technology is best fit for the job at hand. If you're storing session data then I don't see how you'd benefit from a graph database. Though if you for some reason need to relate users, groups, etc. it might make more sense, but I still don't think you'd really benefit from a graph database unless your relations fit a the graph structure. Moreover, with redis you can actually define your own indexes per your needs, though it can get overwhelming if the relations become too complicated. That's when I'd consider other options. However, if you're just storing simple session data then I don't see any reason to use anything but key-value storage. It'll likely be faster, and easier to implement because its actually designed for this.

In addition I cannot see a key-value database like memcached or redis being "too slow". If you're intent is to optimize I think you're making a premature decision.

Comment: the only reason is i am already using orient db in my project. i tought maybe i can use only orientdb instead of "redis + orientdb" there will be no graph feautures in the session db. I tought maybe i can use memory DB for session storage if there is no problem

Comment: I haven't used OrientDB, but you'll probably still need to host another OrientDB server set to use in-memory as your storage medium. So you're only really avoiding including another dependency. Though using OrientDB isn't a terrible choice for session storage, its doesn't seem ideal. Redis will have lower memory overhead, better memory management, and will likely be faster because it uses hashmaps/key-value type indexes and its developed in C.